# Cannot read json range as pgtype.Int4range

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx

I am trying to read a range as json but I am seeing an issue while I do json.unmarshal.

here is a test code-

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "testing"

    "github.com/jackc/pgtype"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

type TestHealthPreference struct {
    HealthRange pgtype.Int4range `json:"health_range"`
    ID          string           `json:"id"`
}

// just a test to make sure unmarshaling works
func TestPreferenceUpdateUnmarshal(t *testing.T) {
    jsonData := `{
        "health_range": "[20,30)",
        "id": "123"
    }`

    var update TestHealthPreference
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &update)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Error while unmarshalling JSON: %v", err)
    }

    assert.Equal(t, 20, update.HealthRange.Lower)
}
```

Error-

```
Error while unmarshalling JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field TestPreference.health_range of type pgtype.Int4range.
```

Is it even possible to read it as pgtype.Int4range? I am guessing this type is for database use only? fwiw, I am using pgx github.com/jackc/pgx/v4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because `"[20,30)"` is not a valid JSON value for the struct `pgtype.Int4range`, and [pgtype.Int4range](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgtype#Int4range) hasn't implemented the [json.Unmarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) interface.

You have to implement the interface yourself to unmarshal `"[20,30)"`:

```golang
type myInt4range pgtype.Int4range

func (r *myInt4range) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    return (*pgtype.Int4range)(r).DecodeText(nil, bytes.Trim(b, `"`))
}
```

BTW

```golang
assert.Equal(t, 20, update.HealthRange.Lower)
```

compares two different types, which should be corrected as:

```golang
assert.Equal(t, int32(20), update.HealthRange.Lower.Int)
```

See the full demo here: https://go.dev/play/p/gGNj3kOBB8k.